# Treat click event on <lightning:icon> as a click on <ui:input>

Tags: lightning-aura-components, event

I have a `lightning:icon` next to a `ui:inputDate` like so. When clicking into the input area, the calendar datepicker pops up, as expected.

Is it possible to treat a click event on the calendar icon as if the user clicked into the box? i.e. is there a way to make the calendar datepicker pop up when the `lightning:icon` is clicked?

```
<div style="display:inline-block;margin-right:10px">
    <lightning:icon iconName="utility:event"/>
</div>
<div style="display:inline-block">
    <ui:inputDate aura:id="dateInput" class="slds-input" displayDatePicker="true" />
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add an onclick to the div and use something similar to (Pardon my naming):

**Component**

```
<aura:component description="myProblemComponent" implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">

    <div style="display:inline-block;margin-right:10px" onclick="{!c.openPicker}">
        <lightning:icon iconName="utility:event"/>
    </div>
    <div style="display:inline-block">
        <ui:inputDate aura:id="dateInput" class="slds-input" displayDatePicker="false" />
    </div>

</aura:component>
```

**Controller**

```
({

    openPicker: function(component,event,handler){
        var y = component.find("dateInput");
        var t = y.getEvent("openPicker");
        t.fire();
    }
})
```

*shorten code as you see fit*

the `ui:inputDate` registers an event handler for `openPicker` that you can fire

> Fire a component event to communicate data to another component. A
>   component event can be handled by the component that fired the event
>   or by a component in the containment hierarchy that receives the
>   event.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/events_component_fire.htm

Although the default component has a cal icon to the right in the input so not sure why it is not showing up in your example

[image]

Comment: Hey Eric - you're right about the cal icon, I took the screenshot when I had `displayDatePicker=false`. Was there anywhere specific you found the `openPicker` event for inputDate? component.find("dateInput").getEvent("openPicker"); is returning null

Comment: Here is the details on the component: https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura/blob/master/aura-components/src/main/components/ui/inputDate/inputDate.cmp - And without seeing how you have everything it is hard to tell. I am displaying the component on the right side of the detail page. updating answer with full component so you can plug and play try it - done. It works without issue for me

Comment: I created a component with only the icon and the inputdate, the difference was that I tested it in a lightning app, and it sounds like you tested it on a page - I'm on my phone now but this sounds like the right approach, I just have some kinks to iron out. Marking as accepted, thanks as always for your help!

Comment: @BrianMansfield - Anytime. Please do leave a comment when you find out why it works not he page and not the lightning app. Interested in knowing that.

Comment: @BrianMansfield - ahh, you may have to add the event to the app dependency although not sure which event it is unless it is `ui:openPicker` that you need to add. Most likely a dependency issue though

Comment: Hi @BrianMansfield and Eric
I have also tried using this component.find("dateInput").getEvent("openPicker"); but getting null and I am not able to follow your comments. Could you please tell me how to open datepicker on click of some other division. (let say <div> click here</div> on click of this div I want my datepicker to open.) I am also using <ui:inputDate> to show datepicker.